# Как исправить скрипт на JS?

Tags: javascript

Есть скрипт помогающий оформить код при редактировании https://jsfiddle.net/L5qhzdh7/

Вопроса 2:

1) Если поставить курсор в конец набранного текста и нажать "цитата" или "код" то теги появятся всё равно в самом начале поля, в первой строке. Что нужно поменять что бы теги вставлялись там где стоит курсор?

2) Функции CodeSelection() и QuoteSelection() абсолютно идентичны - только теги разные вставляются, можно ведь сократить это код... Как это правильно сделать и какое событие ловить для общей вынесенной части функции, все мои попытки привели к неработоспособности.

```
Code.onclick = function ShowSelection()
{
  var textComponent = document.getElementById('Editor');
  var selectedText;
  // IE version
  if (document.selection != undefined)
  {
    textComponent.focus();
    var sel = document.selection.createRange();
    selectedText = sel.text;
  }
  // Mozilla version
  else if (textComponent.selectionStart != undefined)
  {
    var startPos = textComponent.selectionStart;
    var endPos = textComponent.selectionEnd;
    selectedText = textComponent.value.substring(startPos, endPos)
  }

  var textareaValue = document.getElementById('Editor').value;
  var textareaValueNew = textareaValue.replace(selectedText,'<code>'+selectedText+'</code>');
  document.getElementById('Editor').value = textareaValueNew;
}


Img.onclick = function ImageSelection()
{
  var textComponent = document.getElementById('Editor');
  var selectedText;
  // IE version
  if (document.selection != undefined)
  {
    textComponent.focus();
    var sel = document.selection.createRange();
    selectedText = sel.text;
  }
  // Mozilla version
  else if (textComponent.selectionStart != undefined)
  {
    var startPos = textComponent.selectionStart;
    var endPos = textComponent.selectionEnd;
    selectedText = textComponent.value.substring(startPos, endPos)
  }

  if(selectedText === ''){
      var ImgURL = prompt("Введите адрес картинки", '');

      if(ImgURL !== null){
          var textareaValue = document.getElementById('Editor').value;
          var textareaValueNew = textareaValue.replace(selectedText,'<img src="'+ImgURL+'">');
          document.getElementById('Editor').value = textareaValueNew;
      }
  }

}


Quote.onclick = function ImageSelection()
{
  var textComponent = document.getElementById('Editor');
  var selectedText;
  // IE version
  if (document.selection != undefined)
  {
    textComponent.focus();
    var sel = document.selection.createRange();
    selectedText = sel.text;
  }
  // Mozilla version
  else if (textComponent.selectionStart != undefined)
  {
    var startPos = textComponent.selectionStart;
    var endPos = textComponent.selectionEnd;
    selectedText = textComponent.value.substring(startPos, endPos)
  }

  var textareaValue = document.getElementById('Editor').value;
  var textareaValueNew = textareaValue.replace(selectedText,'<q>'+selectedText+'</q>');
  document.getElementById('Editor').value = textareaValueNew;
}
```

Comment: я бы посоветовл создавать <q>, <code>, как ДОМ ноды, а сам текст вставлять через innerHTML. Или это принципиально нужно в поле ввода?

Comment: @ddeadlink да в поле ввода, это типа визуального редактора